# Validate credentials against AD

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Might be a brainfart but,
whenever i try to validate my credentials in my webform against ad it always returns true(approved), why is that? This is just a test to make sure its working whenever i click the "submit" button:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username1 = uniloginTextBox.Text;
        string password1 = passwordTextBox.Text;

        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "cv.local"))
        {
            // validate the credentials
            bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(username1, password1, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
        }

        if (IsValid == true)
        {
            Label.Text = "approved";
        }
        else if (IsValid == false)
        {
            Label.Text = "Denied";
        }
```

Comment: You're checking some object named `IsValid`, not the bool `isValid` (one begins with capital, other does not), which you couldn't check anyway because it won't exist in that context. Move `isValid` outside the using, set it to false by default, set its value inside the `using` and check it afterwards with `Label1.Text = isValid ? "Approved" : "Denied";`

Comment: yes, isValid with a small i is inside the using block. It dies as soon as the block ends. IsValid with a capital I is a different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is checking the truth value of an object named `IsValid`. The `bool` you've created is named `isValid`. Notice one begins with a capital and the other does not.

The bool `isValid` won't exist outside of your using block as it's declared inside. Move `isValid` outside of the using statement like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Username and password text
    var username1 = uniloginTextBox.Text;
    var password1 = passwordTextBox.Text;

    // isValid defaults to false
    bool isValid = false;

    // Check credentials against AD
    using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "cv.local"))
    {
        // Set value for isValid
        isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(username1, password1, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
    }

    // Achieves the same as your if statement
    Label.Text = isValid ? "Approved" : "Denied";
}
```